# Playing media in Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player

my app is playing some audio files, but if the user hits the play button twice, it will play then it will play again (something like that).

I would like the next action to happen JUST when the first execution of the audio file is over.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource((endMidia));
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}                                        
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Any help is appreciatted!

Answer (score 1):

You can make check with [MediaPlayer.isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

There are listeners on `MediaPlayer` events like `OnCompletionListener`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)

and others

Answer (score 1):

check **if** condition as shown in  below code

```
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource((endMidia));
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
   if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){                                    
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```